# Rails 3 STI: removing association in subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, sti

So I'm currently working on a new version of a JSON API which needs to be backwards compatible. I have the following models set up:

```
class Student
  # this is a student of type "version 1"
  has_one :student_information
  has_one :family_information
  #...
end

class V2::Student < ::Student
  # this is a student of type "version 2"
  # which accesses the same table as the version 1
  self.table_name = 'students'
end
```

So, all the associations are getting inherited, which is fine. But the version 2 of the student is defined the way, that `family_information` is being removed. In order to stay compatible with the API version I can't remove it from the `Student` base class, but want to remove it from the `V2::Student` class.

How can I achieve this? Is this even necessary? Better solutions?

Comment: Hey Man, I am facing the same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a V1 also just like the V2 and put the associations in V1 instead of direct in the Student class.

```rb
class Student
  #...
end

class V1::Student < ::Student
  # this is a student of type "version 1"
  has_one :student_information
  has_one :family_information
  self.table_name = 'students'
end

class V2::Student < ::Student
  # this is a student of type "version 2"
  # which accesses the same table as the version 1
  self.table_name = 'students'
end
```